# Django Haystack search inside index template isn't return anything

Tags: django, django-haystack

So I've followed the haystack documentation but I can't make the jump into my app.

Following the instructions I have got templates/search/search.html at search/ returning results but I want my index page (my frontpage) to return the search results.

Search from the index just doesn't return anything. I'm new to Django and need some help, I'm sure I need to create a view to do this but I don't know how.

My index views.py:

```
def index(request):
     return render_to_response('index.html', {'categories': Category.objects.all(), 'entries': Entry.objects.all()[:5]})
```

My index.html template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load markdown_deux_tags %}

{% block title %}The NRSLTD Knowledge Base{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<div class="search">
    <h2>Search</h2>
    <form type="get" action=".">
        <input type="text" name="q" value="Search here" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">
        <button class="btn btn-custom" type="submit">Search</button>
        {% if query %}
        <h3>Results</h3>

        {% for result in page.object_list %}
            <p>
                <a href="{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}">{{ result.object.title }}</a>
            </p>
        {% empty %}
            <p>No results found.</p>
        {% endfor %}

        {% if page.has_previous or page.has_next %}
            <div>
                {% if page.has_previous %}<a href="?q={{ query }}&amp;page={{ page.previous_page_number }}">{% endif %}&laquo; Previous{% if page.has_previous %}</a>{% endif %}
                |
                {% if page.has_next %}<a href="?q={{ query }}&amp;page={{ page.next_page_number }}">{% endif %}Next &raquo;{% if page.has_next %}</a>{% endif %}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% else %}
        {# Show some example queries to run, maybe query syntax, something else? #}
    {% endif %}
    </form>

    {% for note in notes %}
    <h1>{{ note.title }}</h1>
    <p>
        {{ note.body }}
    </p>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

<div class="wrap">
    <h2 id="title">View the last five entries made and the most recent categories added.</h2>
    <div class="cat">
        <h2>Categories</h2>
        {% if categories %}
            <ul>
            {% for category in categories %}
                <li><a href="{{ category.get_absolute_url }}">{{ category.title }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% else %}
            <p>There are no entries.</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>

    <div class="ent">
        <h2>Entries</h2>
        {% if entries %}
            <ul>
            {% for entry in entries %}
                <li><a href="{{ entry.get_absolute_url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
                {{ entry.text|markdown }}
                {{ entry.tags }}
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% else %}
            <p>There are no entries.</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Urls.py:

```
# Search
(r'^search/', include('haystack.urls')),
```

I have copied the search/search.html into the index.html and it looks the same, I just need it to return the results in the same was as search/search.html does.

**UPDATE:**

Added settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'south',
'knowledgebase',
'markdown_deux',
'haystack',
'bootstrap3',
)

HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.whoosh_backend.WhooshEngine',
    'PATH': os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'whoosh_index'),
},
}

# This line enables signal processor that will update_index for every change in models
HAYSTACK_SIGNAL_PROCESSOR = 'haystack.signals.RealtimeSignalProcessor'
```

Comment: Which search backend are you using? Provide your settings.py

Comment: I'm using Whoosh. I've updated my question with a snippet from my settings.py

Comment: But your view isn't doing any searching! Where are you expecting the results to come from? It isn't even passing anything called "query" to the context, so the if statement will never be true.